# Correlating custom events in Flurry

Tags: ios, flurry

I'm trying to capture the events in my app using Flurry. My app is a video streaming app where each video is associated with an artist. An artist can have N number of videos.

I want to capture the list of videos watched by users for a particular artist over a range of date/time.

I went through the Flurry documentation & forums and found that we can capture the custom events. In my case, I can capture "video watched" and "Artist of a video" as two different custom events. With these over the period, I can track the most watched videos and most watched artists.

But is there any way in Flurry, where we can correlate these two custom events to track the list of videos of an artist which users watched the most?

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vasu N

Answer (score 0):

I would have just one event: Video Watched and add a parameter named Artist with the id of the artist, you can also add the id of the video to it or any other parameter that you find useful.